# How can I get mercurial to ignore a particular folder that has a space in its name

Tags: mercurial

There are plenty of examples of how to ignore folders in Mercurial but I'm having trouble ignoring a folder that has a space in its name. I want to ignore a folder called `Translation Files`

I've tried wrapping in it quotes but no success. Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: You don't say if you're talking about in a `.hgignore` file or in the `-I` (ignore) option to `commit` and other commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's something I'm not reading out of your question, the simple approach works best:

```
glob:Translation Files/
```

This works for me, I added this directory, added a file, verified that commit/addremove etc. wanted to add it, then redid the operation but added the ignore mask, and the file was ignored.

Comment: Oops, hugely embarassed. The problem was that I had actually called my folder Tranlation Files (note the missing 's'), when it should have been Translation Files.

Answer (score 1):

.hgignore:

syntax: glob
Tranlation Files/